# Tektronix DPO 3052 encoder repair

Tags: repair, encoder, tektronix

Two encoders are showing similar behavior as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YuxlrwbJRm8).

[image]

But I do not have spare encoders. I have fond this on the ebay.

[image]

The part number is <s>260-2791-00</s>. Edit: no, it is part number with detents, the ones on the pic does not have detents, therefore must have different p/n. But look same.

My question - would I be able to repair existing encoders? What do we expect to find inside the assembly? I am sure I can open the body (hopefully the deal is in cleaning), but if it has set of small springs inside I am afraid to lose or damage them or be unable to assemble them back properly.

Anyone had experience with such devices?

Edit: found [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/510180/need-help-understanding-a-rotary-encoder-datasheet), will try to repair, we'll see.

---

**Update:** desoldered two encoders, opened them to find out that are heavily greased.

[image]

I can't get what do to with the grease: [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/443918/how-to-best-clean-this-sealed-mechanical-rotary-encoder-volume-knob) says to apply it back (onto contacts?), [this](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/how-to-clean-grease-a-rotary-switch.398817/) and [this](https://support.newgatesimms.com/yamaha-amplifier-case-study-potentiometer-damping-grease/) say no grease on the contacts (this is also what I would do). Does it really need a grease on the contacts, or needs only on rotating parts? I would prefer putting the whole stuff into the spirit, clean everything and then apply grease only to the friction plastic surfaces.

---

**Final update:** I found [this excellent post](https://gearspace.com/board/showpost.php?p=13425483&postcount=14&s=e712946e6fee48ec5765012c73ce4ae5) and decided not to proceed further. Using small screwdriver redistributed grease on the surface, slightly bent wiper contacts up, and assembled everything. We'll see tomorrow if it still works...

**Final update 2:** after installation and assembly scope still functions :) and the knobs behave slightly better than before, but sometimes still erroneous. Conclusion - these encoders must be replaced.

Comment: Would you *prefer* an encoder with indents? For some things they are easier to use than ones without.